# MySQL Select different values in the same row

Tags: mysql, database

Hello I got a problem because I want to select 3 different values from the same table and display them in different columns on the same row.
I think that can be achived but I cannot get it right.
This is the table I want to extract the data from:

```
select * from mantis_custom_field_string_table limit 20 \G;                                                                   *************************** 1. row ***************************
field_id: 4
  bug_id: 1957
   value: COCO-AB-00132
    text: NULL
*************************** 2. row ***************************
field_id: 3
  bug_id: 1957
   value: COCO-AB-00132-100.220.181.65
    text: NULL
*************************** 3. row ***************************
field_id: 7
  bug_id: 1957
   value: Lore Ipsum Lalala.
    text: NULL
```

This is the first approach I am trying:

```
select summary,value from mantis_bug_table inner join mantis_custom_field_string_table on mantis_custom_field_string_table.bug_id=mantis_bug_table.id where (field_id=4 or field_id=3 or field_id=7) and id=1957;
+------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| summary                                  | value                                                                                                   |
+------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| This is the summary | COCO-AB-00132-100.220.181.65                                                                            |
| This is the summary | COCO-AB-00132                                                                                           |
| This is the summary | Lore Ipsum Lalala.     |
+------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is what I want:

```
+------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| summary                                  | ID |      COCO |  Lore                                                                            |             
+------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| This is the summary | COCO-AB-00132-100.220.181.65     | COCO-AB-00132    | Lore Ipsum Lalala                                                                  |
```

And this is what I have also tried, but without success

```
mysql> select summary,value as ID, value as COCO, value as Lore  from mantis_bug_table inner join mantis_custom_field_string_table on mantis_custom_field_string_table.bug_id=mantis_bug_table.id where (field_id=4 or field_id=3 or field_id=7) and id=1957 \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
summary: This is the summary
     ID: COCO-RT-00132-100.220.181.65
   COCO: COCO-RT-00132-100.220.181.65
   Lore: COCO-RT-00132-100.220.181.65
*************************** 2. row ***************************
summary: This is the summary
     ID: COCO-RT-00132
   COCO: COCO-RT-00132
   Lore: COCO-RT-00132
*************************** 3. row ***************************
summary: This is the summary
     ID: This is the summary.
   COCO: This is the summary.
   Lore: This is the summary.
```

I hope someone can help me with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know what are you searching for, you can use inner select query
For example

```
SELECT
(
  SELECT value
    FROM mantis_custom_field_string_table
   WHERE
         "put your clause here"
   LIMIT 1
) AS summary,
(
  SELECT value
    FROM mantis_custom_field_string_table
   WHERE
         "put your clause here"
   LIMIT 1
) AS ID,
(
  SELECT value
    FROM mantis_custom_field_string_table
   WHERE
         "put your clause here"
   LIMIT 1
) AS COCO,
(
  SELECT value
    FROM mantis_custom_field_string_table
   WHERE
         "put your clause here"
   LIMIT 1
) AS LOREM
```

One important thing to know is that each one your inner select queries must return a **SINGLE ROW**